# Phonegap 3.0.0 Android Video

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, video.js, cordova-3

I know there have been plugins released for the android video issue because it does not support HTML5 for earlier versions of phonegap, such as videojs and simon macdonalds fix, but I don't see any fixes for phonegap 3.0.0 with this issue. Has anyone solved this issue or come up with a fix for it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was having that same issue with PhoneGap 3 and HTML5 video tags in Android.
Have you tried this plugin? https://github.com/jaeger25/Html5Video